# Trouble showing alert after iterating through an array

Tags: javascript

I have an input field where the user inputs their zip code which I then attempt to match to a zip code within an array. While the following works, I need it to actually show an alert dialog once saying that zip code wasn't found, however, it current pops up a lot even if the zip code is in the list.

Here's my snippet:

```
_zipcodeBtn.onclick = function(){
  var userZip = _zipcode.value;

  for (var i = 0; i < zipcode_list.length; i++) {
    if (zipcode_list[i] === userZip) {
      console.log('works');
      break;
    } else {
      alert("repeating");
    }
  }
};
```

I want it to check if their zip is available without it also repeating the else statement multiple times. Whats the best way to prevent this?

Comment: *"without it also repeating the else statement multiple times"* Huh? Repeating its body is **the whole point** of a `for` loop. It's exactly working as it should be. Remove code you don't want to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a loop here. You can just say:

```
if (!zipcode_list.includes(userZip)) alert("Doesn't work!");
```

If you must use a loop, then just set a flag by default to `false` and then,  if the zip is found set it to `true`. Then you can check it outside the loop:

```
/* Create a flag and set it by default to false. */
var found = false;

/* Loop */
for (var i = 0, l = zipcode_list.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (zipcode_list[i] === userZip) {
      /* Set the flag to true and stop the loop. */
      found = true;
      break;
  } 
}

 /* Check whether the zip was found in the array. */
 if (found) console.log("Works!");
 else alert("Doesn't work!");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Angel! I used the second option in case they wanted to try another zip code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @mur7ay.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to find an item in an array, by referencing the array's `indexOf()` method ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).

```
if (zipcode_list.indexOf(userZip) != -1) {
    //found - do something
} else
    alert('Zip not found!');
```

As Angel Politis shows, you can also use `includes()` if you literally just want to know whether an item is in an array, not its actual position within it.

Sidenote: it's important to check against -1 when using `indexOf()` because it returns the index at which the search is found - or -1 if it's not. If the search is found at the first key, this is 0, and 0 is a falsy value, which can catch people out sometimes when they do things like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
if (arr.indexOf(1))
    alert('success');
else
    alert('failed');
```

You'd think the success alert would fire here, but actually it'll be the failure alert, because `indexOf()` in this case returns 0, and 0 is a falsy value when it's interrogated in a condition.

Comment: I've tried this and the other solution provided, and while it does function properly when the zip code matches to one in the array, if one doesn't matter then it repeats (alert pop-ups) say 18 times for each zip code in the array which is what I'm ultimately trying to prevent.

Comment: Sounds like you've merged my code your loop. The scenario you describe would apply only if you were running in a loop.